# pull api, create file, push to netlify with Gitlab CI

Tags: json, gitlab, netlify, hugo

So I have a Gitlab CI that will, currently, queue up every Monday at 6am and run. All it does is push a build command to Netlify using a build hook.

My current set up is Gitlab for VC, Netlify for deployment, HUGO as my static site generator.

No problem.

Here's what I'm trying to do: I have access to an API that shows me all of the items on a particular website (podcast) as JSON.

I want to write a Gitlab CI that will fetch the API, grab the newest thing, and then create a new page with `hugo new content/{title}.md`, and fill that file's front matter with something from the JSON object.

I'm not even sure this is possible, or that this is the best route to go.

But basically, every time I upload a new podcast, I want Gitlab and Netlify to rebuild my website with a dedicated page for that episode.

Comment: Your 'question' does not contain a question.

Answer (score 0):

The **easiest** route is to parse the JSON with javascript and NOT create a seperate page, but I guess you figured that out already.

The way you describe is also possible. Any server-side script can fetch the API and run the hugo new command (as long as it is on the same/deployment server). I would do it in PHP on my server, but I am kind of old-fashioned. Gitlab CI can probably do this too, but I have never tried it.

You did not really ask a question, but did I answer it anyway?

Comment: Yeah I'm sorry it was late and I was tired when I was trying to ask. My question was *how* can I do this with Gitlab CI.

I'm sure it *can*, I'm just not sure how. For now I'm just creating the pages manually.